# Adding a circle around icon

Tags: html, css

I don't have much experience with styling and I'm trying to create a marker that looks like in the attached

[image].

Till now I managed to do the changes like in the attached code snippet, but I can't make it display the icon like in the image.

```css
.markerClass {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: x-large;
  line-height: 97%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}

.markerClass:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="markerClass">
  <span style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border-radius:50%"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
  <span style="background-color: black; color: white; padding-left: 4px">MyName</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it look ok?

Comment: just add display:inline-block; and dimension to your first span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set negative margin for the first span and set `border` for it.

```css
.markerClass {
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: x-large;
    line-height: 97%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}

    .markerClass:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 29px;
        left: 8px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
        border-top: 13px solid red;
    }
.markerClass{margin-left: 20px;}
.markerClass span:first-child {margin-left: -15px; border: 5px solid #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="markerClass">
  <span style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border-radius:50%"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
  <span style="background-color: black; color: white; padding-left: 4px">MyName</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your icon has less `width` than `height` , so to make it circle add `padding` to left & right like this :

```
padding: 0 3px;
```

And add a white `border` to icon like this:

```
border:3px solid white
```

> You can specify styles according to need (like `border-width` `padding`)

```css
.markerClass {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: x-large;
  line-height: 97%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}

.markerClass:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="markerClass">
  <span style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border-radius:50%;padding:0 3px;border:3px solid white;"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
  <span style="background-color: black; color: white; padding-left: 4px">MyName</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

```
.markerClass {
background: black;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: x-large;
line-height: 97%;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-color: red;
border-style: solid;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
border-left: none;
margin: 10px;
}

.markerClass:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid red;
    }
   .markerClass{
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .phone {
    margin-left: -5px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 9px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="markerClass">
<span class="phone" style="background-color: #808080; color: white; border-radius:50%"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
<span style="background-color: black; color: white; padding-left: 4px">MyName</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

links

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).